# Changing the name attached to my MacBook Pro

Tags: apple-id, accounts

I bought a MacBook Pro Retina, and it's my first OS X computer. During setup, I had a brain lapse and entered my mom's email address instead of my own. I don't remember what it was I was setting up, but I believe it had something to do with Apple ID. My mom has a MacBook herself.

I'm not talking about the computer name. The computer is named correctly. Also, iTunes and the App Store are linked to my own Apple ID.

Later, when I opened up Xcode, I found that new Objective-C files have my mom's name in the comments section at the top.

I just installed Parallels and also found that during registration my mom's name and email address appear pre-filled for me.

I have no idea what to do to change this. Any idea how I can retake "ownership"?

Comment: So the computer name shows up correctly in the Sharing pane of System Preferences?

Comment: @daviesgeek, yes, it does!

Comment: Well, it seems like you fixed the issue! I didn't even know that...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to change your personal contact card in Address Book, soon to be Contacts in Mountain Lion.

In order to do this, launch Address Book and create a card with your information in it.

Then, while your card is selected, go to the Card menu and select "Make This My Card".

**Note:**  I'm not sure if Xcode has a stores this info elsewhere or not, but anything new that you install will definitely get this updated info.

Comment: Great, thank you. I think that was it. When I opened Address Book I saw my mom's email in there with a silhouette icon next to it, denoting that it's default. I'm pretty sure this should fix it.